# Execute command fails when window is closed

Tags: java

I made a basic text editor. When I close the window I get an error in the execution of the command, whether I have saved the text file or not.

```
Error in command execution

Error executing target org.codehaus.mojo: exec-maven-plugin: 1.5.0: exec (default-cli) in EditorText project: Command execution error: Process exited with error: 1 (Output of value: 1) -> [Help 1]
```

This is the class constructor:

```
 public FraEditor() {
    initComponents();
    loadFont();
    loadSizes();

    //Ventana centrada en la pantalla
    Dimension size = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    this.setLocation(size.width / 2 - this.getWidth() / 2, size.height / 2 - this.getHeight());

    //Deshacer
    deshaz = new UndoManager();
    addUndoManager(deshaz, jTextPane1);

    //Rehacer
    rehaz = new UndoManager();
    addUndoManager(rehaz, jTextPane1);

    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {

            //Le preguntamos al usuario si quiere guardar o no antes de cerrar el editor
            int confirmar = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "¿Quiere guardar el documento antes de cerrar el editor?");

            //Si la respuesta es afirmativa guardamos y salimos
            if (JOptionPane.OK_OPTION == confirmar) {
                save();
                System.exit(1);
            } //Si la respuesta es negativa solo salimos
            else if (JOptionPane.NO_OPTION == confirmar) {
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
System.exit(1);
```

A non-zero exit status indicates an error. Refer to the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit-int-) for method `exit`.
Try changing that to:

```java
System.exit(0);
```